# A clean Homebrew won't install anything

Tags: macos, homebrew

I was trying to install rabbitmq on OS X 10.6.8 with homebrew, and it failed.. so I tried wiping out my Homebrew installation and reinstalling.  Howevever, now I get the same failure message for anything I try to install.   I don't see any way to debug this either.  Has anyone seen this before?  I have XCode 3.2.6 installed as well.  Here, I try to install git with

```
brew install git -v
```

Output

```
    make -C templates DESTDIR='' install
: no custom templates yet
install -d -m 755 '/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.7.1/share/git-core/templates'
readlink: illegal option -- f
usage: readlink [-n] [file ...]
usage: dirname path
ls: /install_*: No such file or directory
(cd blt && tar cf - .) | \
    (cd '/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.7.1/share/git-core/templates' && umask 022 && tar xof -)
/bin/sh: line 0: cd: /usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.7.1/share/git-core/templates: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
==> Exit Status: 2
http://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/git.rb#L40
==> Environment
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.8
HEAD: 9a6bd3473936175163a642e28f6ce0b8a659cf6d
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/Library/Homebrew
Hardware: 8-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.6.8
Kernel Architecture: x86_64
Ruby: 1.8.7-249
/usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
Xcode: 3.2.6
GCC-4.0: build 5494 
GCC-4.2: build 5666 
LLVM: build 2335 
MacPorts or Fink? false
X11 installed? true
==> Build Flags
CC: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
CXX: /usr/bin/g++-4.2
LD: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
CFLAGS: -O3 -march=core2 -w -pipe
CXXFLAGS: -O3 -march=core2 -w -pipe
MAKEFLAGS: -j8

Error: Failed executing: make prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.7.1 install
These existing issues may help you:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/6257
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/6820
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/6971
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/7462
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/8030
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/8230
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/8244
Otherwise, please report the bug:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/checklist-before-filing-a-new-issue
:~ $
```

Comment: This is a programming question about getting a development library up and running on OSX. Please do not migrate to SuperUser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming homebrew pulled down the files to `/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.7.7.1` it looks like you might have an issue with the make command.  A few things to try:

1. Check to see which 'make' is being used : `which make` by default should be at /usr/bin/make.
2. If #1 is pointing where you would expect you might try to build a simple hello world project with a make file just to check that it's working properly.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I was having a problem with the make install step, which i've narrowed down. It looks like Homebrew looks for files on the PATH that have filenames matching install_* and does something funky with them... (maybe just runs them blindly?) I had some install scripts on my path named install_*, and those seemed to be interfering with Homebrew. Once I removed them from the PATH, Homebrew acted normally again.

Comment: @noli: It would seem odd that make would blindly install.  More than likely OSX is treating the 'install' as a target  passed to the make command, which I believe would search your path for the "install" target.  Regardless of my thoughts, glad to hear it has worked out for you.